# Laravel Auth for Android login

Tags: android, laravel

I have a project that includes Android apps and web application using Laravel. So, I'm using Laravel built-in auth for the login process and uses the Laravel bcrypt for the password field in the database. How can my Android apps login with the database that are hashed by bcrypt?

I've read some questions and their solution is to use jBCrypt, is it safe and compatible with Laravel's bcrypt?

Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: Where is your problem?? I am also using Laravel api in my android app.

Comment: @The_ehT the problem is on the authentication for login. So, the android app will take the users data from the database but the password is hashed by bcrypt, how can I authenticate the user?

Comment: Why would this be different then any laravel web app? You post the form data to endpoint then use https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authentication#authenticating-users

Comment: @The_ehT so, I have to send the user input for email and password from the android app to Laravel?

Comment: what is another way/ how was you way of authentication?

Comment: @The_ehT I use Laravel built-in auth

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120616/discussion-between-the-eht-and-yoksan-herlie).

Comment: you must be having default auth routes in  your laravel project. right ?

Comment: how you are sending the data to server from android app. volley?